# conexão django com sql express 2017

Tags: sql-server, django

Minha versão  python é : 3.7.5 minha versão do django é : 3.0.2
quando executei o comando 'pip install django-pyodbc-azure' ele desinstalou minha versão django e instalou a versão 2.1

No arquivo de settings estou fazendo assim :
'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'projeto',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'minha senha',
        'HOST': 'o nome do host que entro no management studio',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': { 'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'},

Quando executo 'python manage.py runserver' mostra o sequinte erro :
'[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]A network-related or
instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is corre
ct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.'

O servidor por padrão já permite coneção remota.

Comment: Rode esse comando "pip freeze" e coloque a saída dele na pergunta para verificarmos a versão e os módulos instalados.

Comment: me retornou isso

Comment: asgiref==3.2.3
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==2.1.15
django-pyodbc-azure==2.1.0.0
django-stdimage==5.0.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
Pillow==7.0.0
progressbar2==3.47.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
pyodbc==4.0.28
python-utils==2.3.0
pytz==2019.3
six==1.13.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
static3==0.7.0

Comment: Eu recomendo você utilizar o módulo https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html. Existe uma pergunta respondida sobre o assunto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415188/connecting-django-to-mssql-server-express-2014-database

Answer (score 0):

Como você está colocando o nome do HOST ?? Ele precisa conter o nome ou endereço do computador e um ID de instância definido durante o procedimento de instalação (SQLEXPRESS por padrão).

```
Use: 'HOST': 'COMPUTER-NAME\\SQLEXPRESS' or 'HOST': '127.0.0.1\\SQLEXPRESS'
```

Você também pode tentar instalar uma versão mais atual do pyodbc, assim:

```
pip uninstall sql-server.pyodbc
pip install pyodbc
```